# How from php variable make javascript button that appears after delay from php variable

Tags: javascript

I am new with JS. So just wanted to ask, how can I do the button with Js that appears after delay from PHP variable(that variable is 10) - 10 seconds. Have no idea, thanks.

Comment: In PHP: `echo "<script>var delay = $delay;</script>"`. Now use that and `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] before posting a question. Your question is too broad and lacks effort on your part

Answer (score 0):

Just let the php echo the delay variable into your javascript code:

```
<script>

  setTimeout(function(){
    button.style.visibility = "visible";
  }, <?php echo $delay ?>);

</script>
```